# how to make webpagetest.org load a website from a different IP address

Tags: webpagetest

I once received instructions from a web hosting support on how to use webpagetest.org to test a website from a different IP address to the one it is currently live at. This enables you to test the website on a different host to see if that host loads the website faster than the current host.

I've had a look at the Advanced Testing > Advanced tab, but I can't see how to achieve this.

**Edit:** from [the Scripting help doc](https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/using-webpagetest/scripting), there is a script command you can use:

```
setDnsName  www1.aol.com    www.aol.com
setDns  www.aol.com 127.0.0.1
setCookie   http://www.aol.com  zip=20166
navigate    http://www.aol.com
```

When I try just 1 line:

```
setDns  www.example.com.au  103.103.103.103
```

I receive error:

> Invalid Script (make sure there is at least one navigate command and
>   that the commands are tab-delimited). Please contact us if you need
>   help with your test script.

Help appreciated.

Comment: "Test Location" on Advanced tab

Comment: That doesn't allow me to load the website from hosting on a different IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to Advanced Testing > Script tab, and entered command:

```
setDns  www.example.com.au  103.103.103.103
navigate    www.example.com.au
```

and this worked for me